# Rails routes for every method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails controller for testing purposes:

```
class MyTestController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def test1
  end

  def test2
  end

  def test3
  end

  def test4
  end

  def test5
  end

  ........
end
```

and following routes:

```
get '/my_test/test1', to: 'my_test#test1'
get '/my_test/test2', to: 'my_test#test2'
get '/my_test/test3', to: 'my_test#test3'
get '/my_test/test4', to: 'my_test#test4'
get '/my_test/test5', to: 'my_test#test5'
........................................
```

How to make one route for every future public method of this controller to exclude a need to add one route per method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
get '/my_test/:action', controller: 'my_test'
```

Comment: @Paul I wrote it from the top of my head, so sorry about this mistake. Now it should work.